# Determine OS from a single command line operation

Tags: linux, windows, shell, cmd

**Introduction:**

I have a 'magic' tool that can perform a command line operation on a machine if I provide the IP.
The tool knows the OS that machine is using and executes the command on cmd/shell based on whether it is windows/linux and returns the output of the command back blindly.

> C:> tool.exe 172.140.56.2 "ipconfig"

**Assumptions:**

1. One OS per machine. Tool has no problem executing the command (whether it fails or not is a different problem)
2. The OS is either windows or linux always.
3. I determine the OS based on the command result

**Problem:**

Using this power of being able to execute a command, I want to determine the OS

**My Solution:**

Execute ipconfig command. If result is

> -bash: ipconfig: command not found

It is linux.

Else if it is like this:

```
Windows IP Configuration
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
...
```

then Windows.

**Question:**

I wanted to know if this is a foolproof way of doing this. I want a command which would not fail under certain scenarios. (say cygwin installed on windows allowing linux commands to succeed. Or ipconfig succeeding on linux under some special scneario.)

I can process the command output with some parser, if that helps in any way.

Just to clear any confusion. It can be ANY command. I ust used ipconfig in my example.

Comment: I assume you can't modify the 'magic' tool in any way since clearly that tool knows somehow and it would seem simplest simply to have it spit that information out at you.

Comment: Yes. consider i cannot dig into the 'magic' tool or even identify how it does its 'magic'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, then `uname` is the ideal command. If it's any Unix-system (including OSX), it'll return the correct variable, and if it's Windows it'll return command not found or similar.

Comment: Yes. This seems like a more sensible command to execute. But let me keep the question open in case someone thinks otherwise.

Comment: I considered `uname` but disliked the "causes an error" aspect. Hence my comment on the OP of `echo "$PATH"`. Which is valid for both OSes and returns clearly distinguishable output on each.

Comment: *"(and I believe also OSX)"* OS X *is* unix. With the (tm), none the less.

Answer (score 2):

Safest way to determine Linux/version is

```
cat /etc/*release
```

Sample output.

```
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17
DISTRIB_CODENAME=qiana
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17 Qiana"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another command that should work is `set`, which displays name and value of each environment variable.  Any shell on Linux supports it (although output is different between `csh` and `bash`).  Output from a Windows system would have `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` and other standard variables in it (see https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html), which are very unlikely to be set in Linux.